# What does this syntax (0 < x < 10) do in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

I thought this syntax `0 < x < 10` equal with this syntax `0 < x && x < 10`. However, today, my program has proven me wrong. Normally, I won't ask this kind of question, what does `0 < x < 10` do? But the compiler accepts it so I hope it has some kind of function.

Here is a part of my code:

```
if (0 <= grade < 59)
        letter = 'F';
    else if (60 <= grade < 69)
        letter = 'D';
    else if (70 <= grade < 79)
        letter = 'C';
    else if (80 <= grade < 89)
        letter = 'B';
    else if (90 <= grade <= 100)
        letter = 'A';
    else
        letter = '?';
```

The result always returns `letter ='F'`, so I thought that the compiler only considers `0 <= grade` as condition. But if that is how compiler works than `letter` should equal `?` when I assign char value or a negative number. However it is not. So I really confused between an error of compiler and 'function of compiler' because if it is then what does `0 < x < 10` do?

Comment: It is mostly meaningless. It is syntactically valid C++, so it compiles, but it does not mean what you think it does, and results in gibberish. \Everytime one sees something like that, it's nearly always an error. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: So you mean it is meaningless syntax?

Comment: `0 < x < 10` means, basically `(0 < x) < 10`. The first comparison, `0 < x` results in either true or false, depending on the value of x, or 0 and 1. And this result gets compared to `10`. Since either 0 or 1 is always less then 10, `0 < x < 10`  is always true. That's why this means complete gibberish, and nonsense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically, what you need to check is operator precedence and associativity.

`(0 < x < 10)`, based on precedence (L -> R) and associativity, can be broken into:

`(0 < x)` which yields a `bool` type

then, `bool < 10 (int)` which is always **true**

An important note is, since `bool` value is either `0` or `1`, the compiler will want to deduce it to `int` like:

```
int grade = 10;
std::cout << (0 < grade < 0); // false
std::cout << (0 < grade < 1); // false
std::cout << (0 < grade < 2); // true

typeid((0 < grade)).name();   // b
```